# C Incrementing pointer address passed to a function ++ operator

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, post-increment

I have a question that is raised from this discussion: [C - modify the address of a pointer passed to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524705/c-modify-the-address-of-a-pointer-passed-to-a-function/21525646)

Let's say I have the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
foo(char **ptr){
    *ptr++;
}

int main()
{

    char *ptr = malloc(64);
    char arr[] = "Hello World!";
    memcpy(ptr, arr, sizeof(arr)); 
    foo(&ptr);
    foo(&ptr);
    printf("%s",ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I was wondering what the output of this program would be and I thought that it  should be `llo World!`.

After some investigation I found the question linked above and realized that, in C, parameters to functions are always passed by **value**. So far there was no problem. When it comes to change `*ptr++;` expression to -> `*ptr = *ptr +1;` output becomes: `llo World!`.

At this point, I can say that I am a little confused. In order to change pointer address, we need a double pointer. That is fine, but why do post increment operations differ? Is it because of the operator precedence?

[Here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) I tried the example in an online C compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The postfix increment operator `++` has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`.  So this:

```
*ptr++;
```

Parses as:

```
*(ptr++);
```

So it changes the parameter value itself, not what it points to.  You instead want:

```
(*ptr)++;
```

Comment: @asevindik *prefix* increment has the same precedence as dereference. *postfix* is higher.

Comment: I'll mark this comment as accepted answer. However, as the others stated below, ```++*ptr``` is also another solution to this problem. For me, a better and more clear statement is ```*ptr = *ptr+1;```
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Postfix operators have higher priority than unary operators. So this expression

```
*ptr++
```

is equivalent to

```
*( ptr++ )
```

The value of the sub-expression `ptr++` is the value of the pointer before its incrementing.

So actually you are incrementing the parameter `ptr` having the type `char **`.  So this incrementing does not change the original pointer and does not make a sense.

Instead you could write

```
( *ptr )++
```

But it will be more clear and less confusing to use the unary increment operator like

```
++*ptr
```

if you want to increment the original pointer itself.

Answer (score 2):

As others have explained, `++` is more important (has a higher priority) than `*`, so your function `foo` actually compiled as this:

```c
foo (char **ptr) {
    ptr = ptr + 1; // This modifies the parameter, which is a copy of a variable, copied *specifically* for this function; hence, modifying it will have no effect outside of the function.
    *ptr; // This is just an expression; it doesn't actually do anything, as the compiler would tell you if you wrote it this way.
}
```

If you change `*ptr++` to `(*ptr)++`, the function will work like this:

```c
foo (char **ptr) {
    *ptr = *ptr + 1; // Sets the variable pointed to by ptr to be equal to itself plus one.
}
```